# Quantikz: no wires in gates spanning multiple wires

Tags: tikz-pgf, quantikz

I tried to use the following `quantikz` code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
\def\myvdots{\ \vdots\ }
\begin{quantikz}
  \lstick[wires=3]{$n$}
 & \lstick{\ket{0}}  & \gate{H} & \gate[wires=3]{U} \\
 & \lstick{\myvdots} & \myvdots &\\
 & \lstick{\ket{0}}  & \gate{H} &\\
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

That produces this result:

[image]

As you can see, the wires in the middle of the `U` gate is not really expected. Any idea how to remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual is a little cryptic but you have asked for three wires, so it has given you three wires! :) What you need to do is specify the number of wires that `U` should span, which is `3`, and then use `nwires` (**n**o **wires**), to say where you do not want wires. That is, you want to use  `\gate[3, nwires=2]{U}`. (More generally, `nwires` accepts a comma separated list.) Using this you obtain:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
\def\myvdots{\ \vdots\ }
  \begin{quantikz}
    \lstick[wires=3]{$n$}
      & \lstick{\ket{0}}  & \gate{H} & \gate[3, nwires=2]{U} \\
      & \lstick{\myvdots} & \myvdots &\\
      & \lstick{\ket{0}}  & \gate{H} &\\
  \end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer is surely +1...I have tried more times but without success. The manual is very cryptic :-). Very good answer.