# Draw measurement on a set of wires using quantikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, quantikz

I want to draw this circuit (Bernstein-Vazirani Algorithm) using the `quantikz` package.

[image]

I could not draw the measurement on a set of wires like the figure. Here is my attempt:

```
\begin{center}

\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate[4]{H^{\otimes n}} & \qw             &  \gate[5]{U_f}&\qw & \gate[4]{H^{\otimes n}} &  \qw\rstick[wires=4]{} &\\
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \qw                     & \qw             &       \qw     &\qw              &                         &\qw&\\
\lstick{$\vdots$}&                         &\lstick{$\vdots$}&               &\lstick{$\vdots$}&                    & & \meter{}\\
\lstick{\ket{0}} &\qw                      &\qw              &     \qw       & \qw             &     \qw      & \qw & \\
\lstick{\ket{-}} &  \qw                    & \qw             &   \qw         &  \qw            &       \qw        &\qw &\\
\end{quantikz}
\end{center}
```

which leads to this:

[image]

Any idea on how to draw the measurement and get rid of the extra wires shown on my attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the option `nwires` and state the row that should not get a wire (see also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/560653/47927)). As for the `meter`, you can use the node style directly:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{quantikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate[4, nwires=3]{H^{\otimes n}} & \qw        & \gate[5, nwires=3]{U_f} & \qw        & \gate[4, nwires=3]{H^{\otimes n}} & \qw \rstick[wires=4]{} \\[-10pt]
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw \\[-10pt]
\lstick{$\vdots$} &           & \lstick{$\vdots$} &           & \lstick{$\vdots$} &           &           & |[meter]| \\[-10pt]
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw \\[-10pt]
\lstick{\ket{-}} & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw 
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to make a few additional vertical adjustments.