# Quantikz remove left wire of gate box

Tags: tikz-pgf, quantikz

I'm trying to draw a circuit with [quantikz](https://ctan.org/pkg/quantikz) using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{$| 0 \rangle$} & \gate[wires=4,nwires=3][1cm]{U_1} & \gate[wires=4,nwires=3][1cm]{U_2} & \ctrl{1} & \qw && \\
\lstick{$| 0 \rangle$} & \qw & \qw & \ctrl{2} & \qw && \\
\ \vdots\ &&& \gate[nwires=0,style={fill=white,draw=white,text height=1cm}]{\vdots} &&& \\
\lstick{$| 0 \rangle$} & \qw & \qw & \ctrl{1} & \qw && \\
\lstick{$| 0 \rangle$} & \qw & \qw & \targ{} & \meter{} & \qwbundle[alternate=2]{} & \measure{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} 
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

which gives me

[image]

I want to remove the wires circled in red. They come from the gate boxes which contain `vdots` and `\measure{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}`. I have intentionally drawn these textboxes as gates with white boxes and white outlines, because it looks better than using a `\text{}` command.

Is this the best way of encoding it? How do I remove the wires to the left of those boxes? I looked at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560653/quantikz-no-wires-in-gates-spanning-multiple-wires) but it wsn't helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a `\gate`, the right way to erase the line is to use `nwires=1`, not `nwires=0`.

As for the `\measure`, there is no easy way to remove this line. But you can make use of the actual definition of the `\measure` macro, which is as follows:

```
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\measure}{O{}{m}}{|[measure,#1]| {#2} \qw}
```

Therefore, as this macro already puts `\qw` into the cell, you cannot place annother connection command afterwards. You can, however, just use `|[measure]|` to draw the node shape into the relevant cell, add the contents in curly braces and finally add the relevant connection command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{$| 0 \rangle$} & \gate[wires=4,nwires=3][1cm]{U_1} & \gate[wires=4,nwires=3][1cm]{U_2} & \ctrl{1} & \qw & \\
\lstick{$| 0 \rangle$} & \qw & \qw & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \\
\vdots &&& \gate[nwires=1,style={fill=white,draw=white,text height=1cm}]{\vdots} & \\
\lstick{$| 0 \rangle$} & \qw & \qw & \ctrl{1} & \qw & \\
\lstick{$| 0 \rangle$} & \qw & \qw & \targ{} & \meter{} & |[measure]| {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \qwbundle[alternate=2]{}
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]